# Use leaflet to display non-geographical tiled images

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tiled, deepzoom, large-image

The leaflet documentation provides an insightful [tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) to work with non-geographical image, but it is based on `imageOverlay`.

```js
const imageSize = {
  width: 2315,
  height: 2315,
}
const maxZoom = 12
const minZoom = 8
const toLatLng = (x, y) => L.CRS.Simple.pointToLatLng(new L.Point(x, y), maxZoom);
const bounds = [
  toLatLng(0, 0),
  toLatLng(imageSize.width, imageSize.height),
];

var viewer = L.map('viewer', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  maxBounds: bounds,
  minZoom,
  maxZoom,
  zoomSnap: 0,
}).fitBounds(bounds);
L.imageOverlay('https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/uqm_map_full.png', bounds).addTo(viewer);
```

```css
#viewer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="viewer"/>
```

How can we transpose this example with `tileLayer` to display a tiled image based on Deep Zoom Image for instance.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#non-map-base-layers

Comment: Thank you @IvanSanchez for sharing the link.  Note that most plugins don't seem to be actively maintained.  Also, I think it's worth demonstrating that a little extra code is enough to make it work with vanilla Leaflet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example using the Duomo dataset from [OpenSeadragon](https://openseadragon.github.io/).

```js
const source = {
  "Image": {
    "xmlns": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008",
    "Url": "https://openseadragon.github.io/example-images/duomo/duomo_files",
    "Format": "jpg",
    "Overlap": 1,
    "TileSize": 254,
    "Size": {
      "Width":  13920,
      "Height": 10200,
    },
  },
};

const maxZoom = Math.ceil(Math.log2(Math.max(source.Image.Size.Width, source.Image.Size.Height)));
const minZoom = Math.ceil(Math.log2(source.Image.TileSize + 2 * source.Image.Overlap));
const toLatLng = (x, y) => L.CRS.Simple.pointToLatLng(new L.Point(x, y), maxZoom);
const bounds = [
  toLatLng(0, 0),
  toLatLng(source.Image.Size.Width, source.Image.Size.Height),
];

const viewer = L.map("viewer", {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  maxBounds: bounds,
  minZoom,
  maxZoom,
  zoomSnap: 0,
}).fitBounds(bounds);
L.tileLayer(`${source.Image.Url}/{z}/{x}_{y}.${source.Image.Format}`, {
  noWrap: true,  // do not query tiles outside the bounds
  bounds: bounds,
}).addTo(viewer);
```

```css
#viewer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: none;
}

img.leaflet-tile {
  height: auto !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="viewer"/>
```

According to Deep Zoom Image [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645077(v=vs.95).aspx), large scale images are represented by a pyramid. Each resolution of the pyramid is equivalent to a level. Levels are counted from the 1x1 pixel resolution as level 0, then resolution is doubled for each following level. Therefore we can compute the resolution from the level: `resolution = 2 ^ level` and infer the level required to display a specific resolution: `level = ceil(log2(resolution))`.

In our example, we use the full image resolution to compute the maximum zoom level and the tile resolution to compute the minimum zoom level.

For the edges of the image, Deep Zoom Image returns non square tiles with a different size. This is why we need to override `leaflet-tile` class properties to prevent leaflet from distorting the image.

Note: the Duomo dataset seems to contain non-edge tiles with invalid size (255px instead of 256px), this is why a white line could appear for some zoom levels. But we don't expect this to happen for a dataset with only valid tile sizes.